# filter by multiple array by matching object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

It's easy to get rid of unmatched object property by single value, like

```js
const person = [
  {name:'james',gender:'male'},
  {name:'john',gender:'male'},
  {name:'chun li',gender:'female'}
]
const gender = ['male'];

let filtered = person.filter( obj => obj.gender === 'male');

console.log(filtered)
```

But what if the gender is both exist, like `['male', 'female']`?  is there any loadash method can help in this case?

Comment: you can check the `indexOf` `obj.gender` in gender array, like this: `let filtered = person.filter( obj => gender.indexOf(obj.gender) === -1);`

Comment: be careful, `'female'.indexOf('male')` is 2

Comment: how's about `let filtered = person.filter( obj => obj.gender === 'male' || (typeof obj.gender === 'object' && obj.gender.indexOf('male') !== -1));`?

Comment: @haipham23 is it possible don't hardcode the string? imagine my list is a list of cellphone's brand, there are more than 50 of them.

Answer (score 3):

The way filter works is by simply supplying it a function that returns true for objects you would like to keep ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)). With that in mind, all you need to do is return true if the gender is either `male` or `female`.

```
let filtered = person.filter((entry) => {
    return (entry.gender == 'male') || (entry.gender == 'female');
})
```

Comment: this is not scalable, imagine it's cellphone's brand, you u have more than 2 item in the array

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize you were planning on an array of 100+ items :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs/#includes)

```
const genders = ['male', 'female'];
let filtered = person.filter(obj => _.includes(genders, obj.gender));
```

Comment: hey this is not bad, there's no problem if the list has more than 100 items?

Comment: Internally it does equality check using o(1) for each element in the array so it will take o(n). Also Lodash takes care or nil check and all.

Comment: This might help, includes vs indexof https://jsperf.com/lodash-includes-vs-indexof/2

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [].indexOf to have desired outcome.

```
const person = [
  {name:'james', gender:'male'},
  {name:'john', gender:'male'},
  {name:'chun li', gender:'female'}
]
const gender = ['male', 'female'];

person.filter((obj) => gender.indexOf(obj.gender)> -1 );
```